# FBO bound but gets nothing drawn into it

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

I'm building a mini-game-engine using C++ and OpenGL 3.3, almost everything is set up, except the post processing effects. I started reading about framebuffers and thought it wouldn't be a problem, how wrong I was...

It seems like the framebuffers is somehow, not being used after being bound. Look the code example:

```
....
GLuint FBO;
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
glLoadIdentity();
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);

GLuint texColorBuffer;
glGenTextures(1, &texColorBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer);

glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 800, 600, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL
);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glFramebufferTexture2D(
GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer, 0
);

GLenum drawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);

GLuint status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "Not completed!" << std::endl;

// Clear the screen
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Read the framebuffer pixels back to check if it 'cleared' to white
unsigned char *img = new unsigned char[104857600];
glReadPixels(0, 0, 800, 600, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
std::cout << img << std::endl;
delete[] img;

exit(1);
....
```

But once I read back the framebuffer pixels I get nothing, just a big empty blog (like lots of line endings). Is there anything wrong with this code? Also, I'm almost sure OpenGL is set up properly, I have lots of drawing after this 'test' block of code.

**Edit**

These are the inizialization flags I'm using:

```
// Initializes and binds VAO (vertex arrary object)
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

// Enabling stuff
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// Other
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

I'm also using SDL 2.0.1, GLEW (Latest release up to this date) and TDM-GCC (GCC 4.8.1)

**Update history:**

1. Modified code with posted sugestions (status check and glTexSubImage2D)
2. Removed glTexSubImage

Answer (score -1):

Read pixel return data from FrameBuffer, but you are rendering to a texture, so use
glGetTexImage or TexSubImage2D to get what's have been drawn onto your texture.

If you still want to use readPixel instead, create a renderBuffer and bind it with glFramebufferRenderbuffer, or you can also use  GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER​, or GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER when creating your fbo to allow the use of readPixel.​

```
....
GLuint FBO;
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
glLoadIdentity();
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);

GLuint texColorBuffer;
glGenTextures(1, &texColorBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer);
```

replace:

```
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 800, 600, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL
);
```

by:

```
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 800, 600, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL
);


glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glFramebufferTexture2D(
GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer, 0
);

GLenum drawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);

GLuint status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "Not completed!" << std::endl;

// Clear the screen
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Read the framebuffer pixels back to check if it 'cleared' to white
unsigned char *img = new unsigned char[104857600];
```

replace:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, 800, 600, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
```

by:

```
glGetTexImage(  GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);

std::cout << img << std::endl;
delete[] img;

exit(1);
....
```

Comment: Still returns nothing. I think it may be a problem related to my driver? Or Glew...

Comment: [link](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html#check) It's always good to check fbo status after initialization. It's also always good to download the very last drivers for your hardware. Could you show me the new code with texsubimage2d...

Comment: Done, updated the original post (Still not working tho)

Comment: Try setting the pixel format both with Alpha RGBA and BGRA on win side`glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 800, 600, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL
);` and `glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            800,
            600,
            GL_BGRA,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            img);`

Comment: Still nothing. (Sorry for not upvoting you, still low rep)

Comment: That answer is just wrong. Readpixels reads back the content of the frame buffer, be it the default framebuffer or some FBO (with renderbuffer or texture attached). Using `glTexSubImage2D` will just further overwrite the data, instead of reading anything back.

Comment: glGetTexture or glTexSubImage2D read back pixels from texture, but if you dont need to update data in texture, ok that glTexSubImage2d is a bit too much. glReadPixel read data from frameBuffer, which is not bound in your example, (glFramebufferRenderbuffer missing), so the only place to get back your pixels is in the texture buff, except if you explicitly bind your fbo to a renderbuffer.

Comment: I thought that the RenderBuffer was optional, that is what most examples say.

Comment: It is, but if you want to read back in a buffer and not in the texture, you have to explicitly create and bind it!